# Codeigniter set sidewide database filter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to have a filter on my site so they only see what they want to see. For example a user enables a location filter and selects that he only wants to see USA profiles. I save the filters in an different database table then userdata and in json.

This sounds quite simple but it isn't :) I want to prevent that I have to paste a long group of code to almost every model function.

Is it for example possible that I create 1 time a function with json_decode and foreaches to generate the right active record (where) codes and insert it in a model function with for example $this->enableFilters(); ? I use multiple models so I actually don't want to add a function to every model.

Is this all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to extend the core model class to include a common function. Look at the [Extending Native Libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) part on the manual.

So, for example, you will create a `MY_Model` to extend `CI_Model` and all your models can extend `MY_Model`. Your common functions can be on `MY_Model` that is available to all child classes.